# Create a Notification System using Python flask for IOT application

Tags: python, apache-spark, flask, apache-kafka, celery

I have created a flask based IOT application where the devices send data regularly via a REST API and that data is stored in a DB.

I want to develop a notification system which send notification to the Mobile APP whenever the thresholds for a particular device exceeds.

The threshold and the time window for each device is stored in DB

Example:

if the temperature of device x for the last 5 minutes is greater that 30 deg C then send a notification to the user.

What would be the best approach to solve this using Python ?

Currently I am using celery beat and running a worker every 1 sec which reads the device data and threshold configured by user from the database and based on the value sends the notification to the APP via PYFCM.

I don't feel this method would be scalable  in the long run.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  Once you have code to post, with a specific problem, *then* you'll have a good post for SO.

Answer (score 0):

That is not particularly "python" or "flask" thing you're asking about.

That's architectural thing. And, after it, that's a design thing.

So, architecturally the typical IoT data are *timeseries* of measurement values tagged with some attributes for distinction by origins, groups, flavors, you-name-it.

As timeseries are being established (received from devices & stored in DB), you typically want to process them with statistical methods to build some functions ready for analysis.

That, in a nutshell, is the architectural disposition.

Now, having all that we can assume what the best design solution could be.
Ideally, that should be the tool that is suited for storing timeseries & equipped with statistical analysis tools as well, in perfect case - having notification adapters/transport too (or that could be a bunch of separate tools that coulkd easily bound together).

Fortunately, they have already exist: look up for Timeseries Databases.

My personal prefrence is InfluxDB, but there exist others, like Prometheus, this recently launched AWS service, etc. Google it all.

Virtually all of them are equipped with stat analysis tools of different kind (in InfluxDB, for instance, you can do it with query language right away, plus there's a powerful stream/batch processor that goes even beyond).

Most of them are equipped with notification instruments as well (e.g. aforementioned Influx stream processor have built-in notification actions on statistical events).

So if you're looking for long term/scalable solution (what's the expected scale, BTW?) - that's one of the best options you've got. Will take some effort/refactor though.

And of course you always can implement it with the tools you've got.

Your "polling workers" solution seems to be perfectly fine for now, next you go for statistical libs specific to your platforms (not familiar with Python, sorry, and your DB isn't known either - can't give a specific advice which to use) and you'll be fine.